# Provider Hosted APP Host on Different Domain IIS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

I want to Host My Provider Hosted APP to another Domain Server e.g.: server1Domain.com

And My SharePoint Site is on spdomain.com.

Should it possible to Host on another domain and Install APP to another domain?

Comment: You can host your **provider** hosted app anywhere you want.

Comment: Hi Kai, Do you have any article?

Comment: For example [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887.aspx)

Comment: Hi Kai, Thanks for your link. I need article where mentioned steps to HOST APP to another Domain i.e.: abcdomain and Site Collection is on another domain i.e: defdomain.

Or Else do you have same scenario then please share me.

I am trying this scenario but Authorization failed from different domain.

Same domain works perfectly.

Comment: In order to authorization work for other domain, you need to register your app first with valid App Domain. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687469.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687469.aspx)

Comment: HI Kai, This is working when Hosted and Install APP in same domain with different Machine.

But I want to do same scenario with different domain.